# Spring MVC IT Test falla porque no encuentra la pagina HTML a devolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, junit

Estoy intentando hacer Test de Integración (JUNIT) sobre una webapp con Maven + Spring 5 + thymeleaf y, cuando lanzo el siguiente test:

```
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder createMessage = get(prueba/alta).secure(true)
            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    this.mockMvc.perform(createMessage).andDo(print());
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> ```
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/templates/prueba/alta.html]")
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:986)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
> (....)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>     ... 75 more
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/templates/prueba/alta.html]
>     at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
>     at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
>     at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
>     ... 87 more
> ```

Sin embargo, si ejecuto la aplicación sobre tomcat 8, funciona correctamente. Así pues, imagino que el problema radica en que al ejecutar el test, el contexto de test no "sabe" como encontrar la ruta que he definido para almacenar las plantillas (`/WEB-INF/views/templates/`). ¿Cómo puedo indicarle al entorno de test cuál es la "ruta" a `/WEB-INF/views/templates/`?

Si el problema es otro, por favor, corregidme, pues estoy un poco perdido.

Comment: Nadie puede ayudarme?

Comment: Es tarde pero , ¿pudiste arreglarlo?

Comment: @Angel, hola, no he encontrado forma de hacerlo, lo he dejado por imposible :-(